# How to select records between two dates in Access?

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access

I need to select records with DateTime between two dates in an Access query. The problem is that when I'm execute this query:

```
select *  from logs 
where date_added >= CDate("01/10/2018") 
AND date_added <= CDate("04/10/2018")
```

I need both border values but the result does not include the last day. Maybe because "04/10/2018" is converted to "04/10/2018 00:00:00" and this value is less than all date_added values of that day.

Can I convert date_added to date only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you can add a day to your date?

```
AND date_added < DateAdd('d',1,CDate("04/10/2018"))
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative expression:

```
SELECT * FROM logs 
WHERE DateValue(date_added) BETWEEN  #01/10/2018#  AND  #4/10/2018#
```

Useful date functions and syntax:

- Date literals can be delimited with `#` in both VBA code and SQL statements, so you don't have to call CDate() on string values.  Examples: `#10/6/2018 4:16 PM#`, `#1/1/2018#`
- Simple mathematical notation can be used to add and subtract whole days from a date value.  Example: `#10/6/2018# + 1 == #10/7/2018#`
- `DateValue( val )` takes arguments of various formats and returns a date/time value with only the date portion.  This answers your question **Can I convert date_added to date only?**  It essentially returns the same date value with the time portion as *00:00:00*.

  Example: `DateValue(#10/6/2018 4:16 PM#) == #10/6/2018#`
- `DateAdd ( interval, number, date )` as already noted by Milad Aghamohammadi.
- Within SQL only (not VBA), one can use the BETWEEN operator.  It works with various data types that have a natural sort order, which includes date values.

  Example `... WHERE [DateField] BETWEEN #1/1/2018# AND #4/1/2018#`